# Stop converting date only string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a DATE type column (no time) in SQL database. When getting the data from database I get a string like '2020-04-30'. When using the string as the input to JavaScript HTML input object, JavaScript takes the string '2020-04-30' as UTC date ('2020-04-30 00:00:00') and convert it to local time. Therefore the HTML input might show the date as '2020-04-29'. Since there is no time information in the original data, there is no basis for conversion based on time zone. What is the best way to handle this situation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not just append " 00:00:01" to the string in Javascript? Or maybe you can use STR_TO_DATE and add a min to it in your mysql query

Comment: First my question is about not convert the string to date based on time zone. So a string '2020-04-30' should just become a JavaScript date object '2020-04-30 00:00:00" in the local time zone, therefore the date part will keep the same.